# How can I access all points of Contour that were created by me?

Tags: c#, image, opencv, unity-game-engine

I created Mat for webcamTexture and I draw contour on a particular area that was determined by me. I want to access all coordinate on contour. Because I want not only to change mat color but also add some color.

I reached x_min,x_max,x_min,x_max point on contour. When I put them for loop and I changed color I didn't get a good result.

Is there any other method that I can use?

Comment: do you want those points in contour order or inp pixel memory order? Is performance relevant?

Comment: One way: Your contour is a list of points. Between the points you draw straight lines. To access the line pixels, you can use cv's LineIterator function

Comment: Thank you, guys. I have accessed all the pixel points and (R-G-B) values ​​of the contour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create get coordinates function for access all points of contour.

> ListMaxAndMins means that max and min points  (x,y)

x_min,x_max,x_min,x_max points of contour.

> Mat image means that your clone of contour.

You can create your clone contour.
`cloneContour = Yourexistingcontour.clone()`

You can access all points of your contour values using the following function.

```
    public List<Point> getCoordinates(List<int> _maxAndMins, Mat image)
    {
        int x_max = _maxAndMins[0];
        int x_min = _maxAndMins[1];
        int y_max = _maxAndMins[2];
        int y_min = _maxAndMins[3];

        List<Point> cordinates = new List<Point>();
        for (int i = x_min; i <= x_max; i++)
        {
            for (int j = y_min; j <= y_max; j++)
            {
                //Debug.Log("i:" + i + " j:" + j);
                if (image.get(j, i)[0] == 0 & image.get(j, i)[1] == 1)
                {
                    cordinates.Add(new Point(i, j));
                }
            }
        }
        return cordinates;
    }
```

Also, you can get the color (R-G-B-A) values that are your accessed points using the following function.

```
public List<double[]> getColor(List<Point> cordinates, Mat image)
    {
        int r = 0, g = 0, b = 0, a = 0;

        List<double[]> colorlist = new List<double[]>();
        List<double[]> colorAvg = new List<double[]>();
        for (int i = 0; i < cordinates.Count; i++)
        {
            int x = (int)cordinates[i].x;
            int y = (int)cordinates[i].y;
            double[] color = image.get(x, y);

            colorlist.Add(color);
            r = (r + (int)colorlist[i][0]);
            g = (g + (int)colorlist[i][1]);
            b = (b + (int)colorlist[i][2]);
            a = (a + (int)colorlist[i][3]);              
            //Debug.Log("Color: "+ color.GetValue(0)+ "-"+ color.GetValue(1) + "-" + color.GetValue(2) + "-" + color.GetValue(3));
        }
        r = r / colorlist.Count;
        g = g / colorlist.Count;
        b = b / colorlist.Count;
        a = a / colorlist.Count;
        colorAvg.Add(new double[4] { r, g, b, a } );


        // Average R-G-B-A values

        Debug.Log("Avg R:" + colorAvg [0][0]);
        Debug.Log("Avg G:" + colorAvg [0][1]);
        Debug.Log("Avg B:" + colorAvg [0][2]);
        Debug.Log("Avg A:" + colorAvg [0][3]);

        return colorAvg ;
    }
```